# My applet is not drawing a lisajouss figure but a sine function

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw a lisajouss figure but instead my program is just drawing a single sine function, why?

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctxt = canvas.getContext('2d');



var x;
var y;
var STARTi = -1000;
var MAXi = 1000;
var yOffset = canvas.height / 2;
var xOffset = canvas.width / 2;
var xAmp = 2;
var yAmp = 3;
var xFreq = 6;
var yFreq = 4;
var phaseDiff = (Math.PI / 2);

//X-Axis
ctxt.beginPath();
ctxt.setLineDash([5, 15]);
ctxt.moveTo(0, canvas.height / 2);
ctxt.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
ctxt.strokeStyle = "rgba(169,169,169)"
ctxt.stroke();

//y-Axis
ctxt.beginPath();
ctxt.setLineDash([5, 15]);
ctxt.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0);
ctxt.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height);
ctxt.strokeStyle = "rgba(169,169,169)"
ctxt.stroke();


ctxt.setLineDash([0, 0]);

function xCoord(a) {
  return 100 * (xAmp * Math.sin(xFreq * (0.3 * a * Math.PI / 180)));
}

function yCoord(a) {
  return 100 * (yAmp * Math.sin(yFreq * (0.3 * a * Math.PI / 180)));
}

x = xCoord(STARTi);
y = yCoord(x);
ctxt.beginPath();
ctxt.moveTo(x + xOffset, y + yOffset)

for (i = STARTi; i < MAXi; i++) {


  ctxt.moveTo(x + xOffset, y + yOffset)
  x = xCoord(i);
  y = yCoord(x);
  ctxt.lineTo(x + xOffset, y + yOffset)



}
  ctxt.strokeStyle = "black"; 
ctxt.stroke();
```

Do I need to change up the way the formulas for the curves are formatted or is there something else wrong, because from what I see, the programm just seems to ignore the xCoord formula and just puts in a normal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the computed `x` coordinate as the parameter for the `y` coordinate function, but you should be passing `i`:

```
x = xCoord(STARTi);
y = yCoord(STARTi);
ctxt.beginPath();
ctxt.moveTo(x + xOffset, y + yOffset)

for (i = STARTi; i < MAXi; i++) {


  ctxt.moveTo(x + xOffset, y + yOffset)
  x = xCoord(i);
  y = yCoord(i);
  ctxt.lineTo(x + xOffset, y + yOffset)



}
```